# Ajuda com Querie em Linq C#

Tags: asp.net, linq, group-by

Tenho uma tabela de mensagens no seguinte esquema:

```
Id | osID |Interessado | Remetente | Destinatario | Msg
--------------------------------------------------
1  |  2   |João        |   João    |   Maria      |bla bla bla...
2  |  2   |João        |   Maria   |   João       |ble ble ble...
3  |  3   |Erik        |   Erik    |   Mark       |O Amadeu ganhou a promoção...
4  |  3   |Erik        |   Mark    |   Erik       |Eu sabia...
5  |  3   |Erik        |   Mark    |   Erik       |Vou pedir as contas...
6  |  4   |Jake        |   Jake    |   Mara       |As oito da noite lá em casa...
```

O cenário que eu preciso é que cada usuario que esteja logado, carregue suas conversas, então eu tenho a seguinte querie:

```
var mensagens = from p in db.Chats
                            orderby p.Id descending
                            where p.Remetente == MinhaPessoa.Usuario || p.Destinatario == MinhaPessoa.Usuario
                            select p;
```

Essa querie retorna todos os registros caso eu seja remetente ou destinatario. Agora, como eu agrupo isso por Ordem de Serviço(osID) e Interessado, e que a ultima mensagem seja exibida?

Comment: acho que é isso aqui mas não vou conseguir testar, se der certo confirma pra eu mandr como resp ok :D 
var mensagens = (from p in db.Chats
                            orderby p.Id descending
                            where p.Remetente == MinhaPessoa.Usuario || p.Destinatario == MinhaPessoa.Usuario
       group p by new {p.osID,p.Interessado}
                            int pn
       select {
       pn.Msg
       }).First();

Comment: deu tudo ok, mas a parte final o intelissense não comprendeu o que seria o "pn" do    int pn select { pn.Msg }).First();  ??

Comment: opa, não é int, é in

Comment: quase la Lucas,, fiz e ficou assim. Eu fiz algumas modificações e ficou assim: var msg = from p in db.Chats
                          orderby p.ChatId descending
                          group p by new { p.ContaId, p.InteressadoId } into g
                          select new { Interessado = g.Key, Conta = g.Select(m => m.Mensagem).First() }; sendo que só retorna somente a msg, eu queria retornar o Interessado e a OSID, ou conta

Comment: beleza, claudinei! responda a própria pergunta pra caso um dia alguém com a mesma  duvida pesquisar e encontrar a sua ;)

Comment: Muito obrigado Lucas. Aprendi bastante!

Answer (score 2):

Com a ajuda do [@Lucas Miranda](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/124686/lucas-miranda) consegui implementar o seguinte:

```
var msg = from p in db.Chats 
orderby p.ChatId descending 
group p by new { p.ContaId, p.InteressadoId } 
into g select new { Interessado = g.Key, Conta = g.Select(m => m.ChatId).First() };
```

Ao inves de selecionar os campos, pego a chave primária e os outros campos implemento através dele